# Finding the set of values of y for which there are no points on a curve

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions

> A curve has the equation:
>
> $$y=2x-5+ \frac{18}{x+4}$$
>
> Find the set of values of $y$ for which there are no point on the curve.

---

What  I did:

Found the *maximum* and *minimum* points:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2- \frac{8}{(x+4)^2} = 0 \implies x=-1 , x= -7$$

Found the corresponding $y$ and the  nature of these turning points, the results are:

$(-1,-5)$  **minimum** point

$(-7,-17)$  **maximum** point

So from  my results I concluded:

$-17\leq y \leq -5$

But this is wrong.

Please Help me find my mistake. And mainly

---

**My question:**

Is there a **quicker** way to do find the set of values? If yes, **How?**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $y$-coordinate calculations are not correct:

$f(-1)=2(-1)-5+\frac{18}{-1+4}=-1\ne-5$

$f(-7)=2(-7)-5+\frac{18}{-7+4}=-25\ne-17$

Comment: (+1) Oops Thank you very much :) Do you know a quicker method?

Comment: No, this is the fastest method I think. :)

Comment: *sigh* But this requires to find the second derivative, etc :/

Comment: How is that possible ? :o Is that possible? :O Please please Telll :D *excited*

Comment: Sketch the function, its oblique asymptote and the points. Now can you say if it's a max or min?

Comment: GOT IT :D Thanks alotttttt :) Appreciate it a lot :)

Comment: No problem ! ;-)

Comment: :) Cheers :) :)

Answer (score 1):

for $x=-1$ we get $-2-5+18/3=-7+6=-1$ and for $x=-7$ we obtain $-19-6=-25$

Comment: (+1) Oops Thank you very much :) Do you know a quicker method?

Answer (score 1):

You could use discriminant theory. Consider the equation as a quadratic in x, and find the set of values of y for which there are no real roots

Comment: Do you think it's possible in this? This is equivalent to $y=\frac{2x^2+3x-2}{x+4}$ , can you show me how you would use the discriminatinant theorem? :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Multiply across and form a quadratic in x. Identify the coefficients which are in terms of y, and set the discriminant to be negative, giving you an inequality to solve for y.